# My raspberry pi and laptop are connected to my mobile hotspot but it's not connecting to VNC nor putty

Tags: raspbian, networking

I have connected both the laptop and raspberry pi to my mobile hotspot it's showing connected in the connected devices as usual but when I entered the raspberry pi IP address in VNC it's not getting connected. I have added enabled and added SSID and password to it.

It is connecting to other mobile phones but not the mobile phone which I am using (mi note 8) try to help me out thank you.

Comment: so, you're trying to connect to the pi from your laptop? what do the other mobile phones have to do with it?

Comment: I'm connecting my Mobile hotspot with the laptop and raspberry pie cuz they should be in same network right?

Comment: yeah, but do mobile hotspots allow connected clients to talk to each other (I don't know the answer to this)

Comment: Hello and welcome – ADD more information about the situation, OS versions on both environments and what you have done till now.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi, and many hotspots is doing client isolation = devices cant communicate with each other, it is considered as a security feature.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the devices connected with each other as Layer-3 network sight. `ping` is the easiest tool that can help you to realize it.
At first, check the IP address of raspberry pi `wlan0` by running `ifconfig` in the terminal and `ping` this IP from your laptop. If everything is fine and it said that the packet doesn't lose, check your VNC configuration on the raspberry pi.

Comment: Yeah I've checked it it's all fine but the problem is even though my mobile hotspot is connected to raspberry pie and laptop but still it's not connected to vnc or putty

Comment: @SyedRiyaz Ok, what is the result of the checking? Are they connected?